# Cache Control Metadata Not working for files in aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website hosted on aws s3 and cloudfront. I tested my website on `GTmetrix` and my website got `16 points` for **Leverage browsing cache**.

So aws docs suggested to specify the `Cache Control` or `Expires` Header. But I only specified  `Cache Control` metadata for the files which gtmetrix suggested me. After specifying cache control metadata on the files I re-test the website, But GT metrix still giving me same points.

Can anyone please let me know How to fix the issue?

Comment: Did you invalidate in CloudFront after setting the headers?

Comment: Yes, I created a new invalidation by going inside cloudfront distribution settings.

Comment: Can you share your website URL?

Comment: sorry! for security reasons I can not share the website url.

Comment: If you put it in GT metrix, it must be public no? Can you share a screenshot of the response headers from the Chrome dev tools maybe?